# RhinoMocks AAA Syntax

Tags: rhino-mocks, arrange-act-assert

I've spent a good part of the day trying to figure out why a simple RhinoMocks test doesn't return the value I'm setting in the return. I'm sure that I'm just missing something really simple but I can't figure it out. Here's my test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CopyvRAFiles_ShouldCallCopyvRAFiles_ShouldReturnTrue2()
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\Myprogram.txt");
        FileInfo[] myFileInfo = new FileInfo[2];
        myFileInfo[0] = fi;
        myFileInfo[1] = fi;
        var mockSystemIO = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISystemIO>();
        mockSystemIO.Stub(x => x.GetFilesForCopy("c:")).Return(myFileInfo);
        mockSystemIO.Expect(y => y.FileCopyDateCheck(@"c:\Myprogram.txt", @"c:\Myprogram.txt")).Return("Test");
        CopyFiles copy = new CopyFiles(mockSystemIO);

        List<string> retValue = copy.CopyvRAFiles("c:", "c:", new AdminWindowViewModel(vRASharedData));
        mockSystemIO.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
```

I have an interface for my SystemIO class I'm passing in a mock for that to my CopyFiles class. I'm setting an expectation on my FileCopyDatCheck method and saying that it should Return("Test"). When I step through the code, it returns a null insteaed. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Here's my CopyFiles class Method:

```
    public List<string> CopyvRAFiles(string currentDirectoryPath, string destPath, AdminWindowViewModel adminWindowViewModel)
    {
        string fileCopied;
        List<string> filesCopied = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            sysIO.CreateDirectoryIfNotExist(destPath);

            FileInfo[] files = sysIO.GetFilesForCopy(currentDirectoryPath);

            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    fileCopied = sysIO.FileCopyDateCheck(file.FullName, destPath + file.Name);
                    filesCopied.Add(fileCopied);
                }
            }

            //adminWindowViewModel.CheckFilesThatRequireSystemUpdate(filesCopied);

            return filesCopied;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "vRAClientPolicy");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);

            ShowErrorMessageDialog(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I would think that "fileCopied" would have the Return value set by the Expect. The GetFilesForCopy returns the two files in myFileInfo. Please Help. :)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A mock will not start returning recorded answers **until it is switched to replay mode** with `Replay()`. Stubs and mocks do no work in the same way. I have written a [blog post](http://mindinthewater.blogspot.com/2010/02/mocking-frameworks-stubs-vs-mocks.html) about the difference.

Also note that you are mixing the old record-replay-verify syntax with the new arrange-act-assert syntax. With AAA, you should not use mocks and `Expect`. Instead, use stubs and `AssertWasCalled` like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CopyvRAFiles_ShouldCallCopyvRAFiles_ShouldReturnTrue2()
{
    // arrange
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\Myprogram.txt");
    FileInfo[] myFileInfo = new FileInfo[2];
    myFileInfo[0] = fi;
    myFileInfo[1] = fi;

    var stubSystemIO = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISystemIO>();
    stubSystemIO.Stub(
        x => x.GetFilesForCopy(Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).Return(myFileInfo);
    stubSystemIO.Stub(
        y => y.FileCopyDateCheck(
            Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).Return("Test");

    CopyFiles copy = new CopyFiles(mockSystemIO);

    // act
    List<string> retValue = copy.CopyvRAFiles(
        "c:", "c:", new AdminWindowViewModel(vRASharedData));

    // make assertions here about return values, state of objects, stub usage
    stubSystemIO.AssertWasCalled(
        y => y.FileCopyDateCheck(@"c:\Myprogram.txt", @"c:\Myprogram.txt"));
}
```

Note how setting up the behavior of stubs at the start is separate from the assertions at the end. `Stub` does not set any expectations.

The advantage of seperating behavior and assertions is that you can make less assertions per test, making it easier to diagnose why a test failed.

Comment: What you are saying makes lots of sense and I think that really helped me understand what's going on here. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Does the method `FileCopyDateCheck` really get called with the **exact** strings `@"c:\Myprogram.txt"` and `@"c:\Myprogram.txt"` as arguments?

I am not sure if `FileInfo` is doing something with `c:\`. Maybe it is modified to upper case `C:\`, which would make your expectation not working.

Maybe try an expectation which does not check for the exact argument values

```
mockSystemIO.Expect(y => y.FileCopyDateCheck(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).Return("Test");
```

For more details about argument constraints see: [Rhino Mocks 3.5, Argument Constraints](http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#ArgumentConstraints)

I am pretty sure that there are also possibilities to make the expectation case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your CopyvRAFiles() method isn't virtual.